# How to extract time out of text with regex in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I need to get the time values out of this string:

```
SomeText 02/02/2020 9:00 AM-02/02/2020 9:15 AM;"Text" 02/02/2020 10:45 AM-02/02/2020 11:15 AM;"Text" 02/02/2020 12:45 PM-02/02/2020 1:00 PM;
```

The pattern and length are not consistent. But time always comes after the date.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What programming language are you using here? Or tool? Any self efforts made?

Comment: Also provide the expected output. And since you said that the pattern and length are not consistent it would be helpful to see some other input/output combinations.

Comment: I am working on google sheets.
SomeText 02/02/2020 9:00 AM-02/02/2020 9:15 AM;"Text" 02/02/2020 10:45 AM-02/02/2020 11:15 AM;"Text" 02/02/2020 12:45 PM-02/02/2020 1:00 PM;     
Expected output:
9:00  AM 9:15  AM 10:45 AM  11:15 AM  12:45 PM  13:00 PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```
=regexextract(J7, rept("\s(\d+:\d+\s[AP]M).+", len(J7)-len(substitute(J7, ":",))))
```

[image: Example]

Note: to convert the returned values to number, try

```
=ArrayFormula(regexextract(J7, rept("\s(\d+:\d+\s[AP]M).+", len(J7)-len(substitute(J7, ":",))))+0)
```

and format the output as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
\d+:\d+ [AP]M
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/8krgFm/1/).

Comment: Hey Jan, thanks for the help.But with the above I am able to get only the first time and i need all of them?

Comment: To answer the above question: i was able to come with the following but it's not working for me (Google Sheets):

I have split the string by ";" and after the separation i used this =REGEXEXTRACT(J7,"\d+:\d+\s[A|P]M") and =REGEXEXTRACT(J7,"\d+:\d+\s[A|P]M$")
But I prefer to get each time in separate cell on the same row and to do it with one formula without this split.